# Windows 7 Mobile Silverlight : Linq to XML issue

Tags: silverlight, windows-mobile, linq-to-xml

I have a XML Document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">

  <title>blahblah</title>
  <subtitle>blahblah.</subtitle>
  <link href="blahblah"/>
  <link href="blahblah"/>
  <updated>blahblah</updated>
  <author>
    <name>blahblah</name>
  </author>
  <id>blahblah</id>

  <entry>
    <title>blahblah</title>
    <content type="html"><![CDATA[&ldquo;some text.&rdquo;]]></content>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

I want to get the entry nodes content information, here's my code:

```
var xmlTreeVal = XDocument.Load("myxml.xml");

        var returnVal = from item in xmlTreeVerse.Descendants("feed").Elements("entry")
                          select new VerseModel
                           {
                               Verse = item.Element("content").Value
                           };
```

The xml document is loading fine (as i could tell via debugging), but it keeps throwing a 'No sequential items found' error.  How do I find the "content" nodes info?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever your XML has a namespace (indicated by the `xmlns` attribute) you must reference the elements by also referencing their namespace. This is done by concatenating the namespace to the element name.

Also, you used `xmlTreeVal` but then reference `xmlTreeVerse` - it's probably not *the* problem but it's an inconsistency in the code you presented.

Try this:

```
var ns = xmlTreeVerse.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
var returnVal = from item in xmlTreeVerse.Descendants(ns + "feed").Elements(ns + "entry")
                select new 
                {
                    Verse = item.Element(ns + "content").Value
                };
```

Comment: Thank You!  Is there a specific reason that you MUST use it?  I had read that you should use it to avoid naming conflicts, but I didn't know you HAD to use it.

Comment: @contactmatt if it's specified in your XML you must use it. You can use the `Where` clause as a workaround as demonstrated in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1145659), but it's not as efficient as referencing the namespace directly. If your XML didn't have a namespace then you can query the nodes by name directly.