# Use LINQ XML with a namespace

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am trying to find nodes in an XML document like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<TrainingCenterDatabase xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabase/v2">
  <Activities>
    <Activity Sport="CyclingTransport">
      <Id>2014-07-08T15:28:14Z</Id>
    </Activity>
  </Activities>
</TrainingCenterDatabase>
```

I aim to extract the node value 'Id' with code like this:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filePath);
List<string> urlList = doc.Root.Descendants("Id")
                          .Select(x => (string)x)
                          .ToList();
Console.WriteLine(urlList.Count);
```

However the count is 0, where I expect 1.

After some debugging and editing the XML I noticed that if I change the `TrainingCenterDatabase` node and remove the attributes to this:

```
<TrainingCenterDatabase>
```

Then the result is a count of 1 as expected.

So my question is how do I take into account the namespaces so that I can get the value when the `TrainingCenterDatabase` node has these attributes?

Comment: Another approach is to use LocalName instead which ignores namespaces: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145659/ignore-namespaces-in-linq-to-xml

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Namespaces in XML can be tricky. I've run into this problem myself a number of times. In all likelihood, the following will fix your problem:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filePath);
List<string> urlList = doc.Root.Descendants(doc.Root.Name.Namespace.GetName("Id"))
                          .Select(x => (string)x)
                          .ToList();
Console.WriteLine(urlList.Count);
```

Basically, this just assumes the underlying element to have the same namespace as your root element. That's true in this case, but of course it doesn't have to be.

The *right* way, probably, is to do it explicitly. Now, granted, that kind of depends on how you're using this and your datasource, so make the decision for yourself, but that would require doing something more like this:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filePath);
List<string> urlList = doc.Root.Descendants(System.Xml.Linq.XName.Get("Id", "http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabase/v2"))
                          .Select(x => (string)x)
                          .ToList();
Console.WriteLine(urlList.Count);
```

The cause for your problem was that the default behavior for `XElement`, when not given an explicit namespace, is to assume *no* namespace.  However, the default behavior for the XML spec is to assume the parent's namespace. In your case, those two were different, so it wasn't able to find the descendant.

Comment: That's worked perfectly. So the reason that the list has a count of 0 in the original example is because it is assumed that the element doesn't have the same name space as the root element?

Comment: @DanSmith good point, I didn't really explain what was wrong. I edited my answer. But yes, basically it was looking for an element with no namespace and a `Name` of "Id," which didn't match the element you were looking for which had a namespace.

Answer (score 0):

It Works...

```
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filePath);
        XNamespace ns = "http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabase/v2";
        var root = doc.Descendants(ns + "Id").Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
        Console.WriteLine(root.Count);
```