# linq to xml add element to node

Tags: c#, xml

I have this code:

```
XNamespace xsi = XNamespace.Get("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
        XNamespace ns = XNamespace.Get("urn:CBI:xsd:CBIBdyPaymentRequest.00.03.09");
        XNamespace ns1 = XNamespace.Get("urn:CBI:xsd:CBIPaymentRequest.00.03.09");
        XDocument xmlDoc = new XDocument(
            new XElement(ns + "CBIBdyPaymentRequest",
            new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", xsi.NamespaceName),
            new XAttribute(xsi + "schemaLocation", "urn:CBI:xsd:CBIBdyPaymentRequest.00.03.09 CBIBdyPaymentRequest.00.03.09.xsd"),
                new XElement(ns +"CBIEnvelPaymentRequest",
                    new XElement(ns +"CBIPaymentRequest",
                        new XElement(ns1 + "GrpHdr",
                        new XElement(ns1 + "MsgId", txtNomeDistinta.Text),
                        new XElement(ns1 + "CreDtTm", dataCreazioneDistinta.ToString("o")),
                        new XElement(ns1 + "NbOfTxs", Convert.ToString(listAnagraficheXML.Count)),
                        new XElement(ns1 + "CtrlSum", getTotalXmlTransactions()),
                        new XElement(ns1 + "InitgPty",
                            new XElement(ns1 + "Nm", Properties.Settings.Default.ragioneSociale),
                            new XElement(ns1 + "Id",
                                new XElement(ns1 + "OrgId",
                                    new XElement(ns1 + "Othr",
                                        new XElement(ns1 + "Id", Properties.Settings.Default.codiceCuc),
                                        new XElement(ns1 + "Issr", "CBI")
                                        )
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        ), //fine GrpHdr
                        new XElement(ns1 + "PmtInf",
                        new XElement(ns1 + "PmtInfId", txtNomeDistinta.Text),
                        new XElement(ns1 + "PmtMtd", "TRF"),
                            new XElement(ns1 + "PmtTpInf",
                                new XElement(ns1 + "InstrPrty", "NORM"),
                                new XElement(ns1 + "SvcLvl",
                                    new XElement(ns1 + "Cd", "SEPA")
                                )
                            ),                           
                            new XElement(ns1 + "ReqdExctnDt", dataCreazioneDistinta.ToString("yy-MM-dd")),
                            new XElement(ns1 + "Dbtr",
                                new XElement(ns1 + "Nm", Properties.Settings.Default.ragioneSociale),
                                new XElement(ns1 + "Id",
                                    new XElement(ns1 +"OrgId",
                                        new XElement(ns1 + "Othr",
                                            new XElement(ns1 + "Id", Properties.Settings.Default.codiceCuc),
                                            new XElement(ns1 + "Issr", "CBI")
                                        )
                                    )
                                )
                            ), //fine Dbtr
                            new XElement(ns1 + "DbtrAcct",
                                new XElement(ns1 + "Id",
                                    new XElement(ns1 + "IBAN", Properties.Settings.Default.iban)
                                )
                            ), // fine DbtrAcct
                            new XElement(ns1 + "DbtrAgt",
                                new XElement(ns1 + "FinInstnId",
                                    new XElement(ns1 + "ClrSysMmbId",
                                        new XElement(ns1 + "MmbId", Properties.Settings.Default.abi)
                                    )
                                )
                            ), // fine DbtrAgt
                            new XElement(ns1 + "ChrgBr", "SLEV")
                         ) //fine PtmInf
                    ) // CBIPaymentRequest
                ) // fine CBIEnvelPaymentRequest
            )  //fine CBIBdyPaymentRequest              
        );
```

if I save the document it works well but if i want to add element with this code

```
var num_trn = 0;
        foreach (Anagrafica an in listAnagraficheXML)
        {
            num_trn++;
            XElement el = new XElement(ns1 + "CdtTrfTxInf",
                new XElement(ns1 + "PmtId",
                    new XElement(ns1 + "InstrId", num_trn),
                    new XElement(ns1 + "EndToEndId", txtNomeDistinta.Text + "-" + num_trn.ToString("D4"))
                ),
                new XElement(ns1 + "PmtTpInf",
                    new XElement(ns1 + "CtgyPurp",
                        new XElement(ns1 + "CD", checkForPurpose())
                    )
                ),
                new XElement(ns1 + "Amt",
                    new XElement(ns1 + "InstdAmt", new XAttribute("Ccy", "EUR"), getImportXmlTransaction(num_trn))
                ),
                new XElement(ns1 + "Cdtr",
                    new XElement(ns1 + "Nm", an.nome)
                ),
                new XElement(ns1 + "CdtrAcct",
                    new XElement(ns1 + "Id",
                        new XElement(ns1 + "IBAN", an.iban)
                    )
                ),
                new XElement(ns1 + "RmtInf",
                    new XElement(ns1 + "Ustrd", getCausalXmlTransaction(num_trn))
                )
            );
            xmlDoc.Element("PtmInf").Add(el);
        }
```

it gives System.NullReferenceException on last line.. I tried with Elements, getName, etc but it gives always same error..

Why??

Comment: I think because xmlDoc not contains _"PtmInf"_ it contain _ns1+"PmtInf"_

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ignore namespaces in LINQ to XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145659/ignore-namespaces-in-linq-to-xml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `Element` method here returns null:

```
 xmlDoc.Element("PtmInf").Add(el)
```

You then call `Add` on it, so the exception is thrown. `Element` gets the first children of `xmlDoc` (of which there is only ever one) and filters it by element name `PtmInf`. The root element in your document is `CBIBdyPaymentRequest` with namespace `urn:CBI:xsd:CBIBdyPaymentRequest.00.03.09`, so there is no match. You've also mistyped `PtmInf` instead of `PmtInf`.

What you probably want is this:

```
 xmlDoc.Descendants(ns1 + "PmtInf").Single().Add(el)
```

Comment: And also you can get namespace from your xmlDoc `var ns1 = xmlDoc.Root.Name.Namespace;`

Comment: @LayonezWronskey that would be the wrong namespace in this case. The root and immediate child are in a different namespace to the target element.

Comment: var ns2 = xmlDoc.Root.Name.Namespace;
                xmlDoc.Descendants(ns2 + "PtmInf").Single().Add(el);

The sequence contains no elements

Comment: @MirkoSalvati that's the wrong namespace, as I explained above. You need `ns1` / `urn:CBI:xsd:CBIPaymentRequest.00.03.09`.

Comment: Some thing like that would work var `ns2 = xmlDoc.Root.Descendants().First().Name.Namespace;`

Comment: @LayonezWronskey nope, that's still wrong. You need to go about 4 levels down to get the right one. It'd be far easier to just explicitly specify it.

Comment: Yeap, you right, if that functions in one class you can store namespaces strings globally and then use them in searching

Comment: not works with var ns2 = xmlDoc.Root.Descendants().First().Name.Namespace;
                xmlDoc.Descendants(ns2 + "PtmInf").Single().Add(el);

and not works with xmlDoc.Element(ns1+"PtmInf").Add(el) or xmlDoc.Descendants(ns1 + "PtmInf").Single().Add(el);

Comment: You have a typo. It's `PmtInf`, not `PtmInf`.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can ignore namespace in searching:

xmlDoc.Elements().Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "PmtInf");